# Deleted file still takes up space?

Tags: sd-card, samba, storage

I was using my SMB server and I uploaded 3GB worth of files. Turns out some things were wrong and I ended up deleting it. Before 60% of my 16 GB SD card was free, now it is more like 16% (2.2 GB ish).  No, I have not downloaded anything. It seems as if the deleted files are not really deleted. Can someone tell me what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: 3GB doesn't account for the almost 14GB you've "lost" - chances are it's nothing to do with the uploaded files - of course, you could use `du` to find any large folders

Comment: Thank you. The downloads folder seems to be the culprit; there were downloaded files from 1 year ago that are no longer needed.